# IntelliJ - hierarchical HTML coloring

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I saw a video where dude had colors in WebStorm (subset of IntelliJ afaik) configured like this:

[image]

What is the way to configure IntelliJ to use such coloring (like different element color per layer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's used by default - no need to configure anything.  If multiple tags of the same type (div, ul, etc) are nested within each other, focusing the nested tag causes the hierarchy to be highlighted. Colors can be configured in Settings/Editor/color&Fonts/HTML, Tag tree (level*)

Comment: I guess you're right, it just feels a bit awkward. I cannot get those colors so bright as on the pic in my IntelliJ (using same screen for that).

Comment: @Xorty There is an `opacity` setting just for that. By changing it you should get more brighter colors.

Comment: AWESOME! that's what I was looking for :)